# Strange behaviour of F# record with FlowDocument

Tags: f#, record

I tried to create an F# record type containing a FlowDocument in Visual Studio 2012 RC somewhat like this:

```
module RecordTest =
    open System.Windows.Documents

    type TestRecord =
        {
            TestName : FlowDocument
        }

    let test = { TestName = new FlowDocument () }
```

The strange thing is, this does not work for me. Visual Studio tells me: `The record label TestName is not defined.` and hovering over the type definition of `TestRecord` does not reveal a tool tip. If I change the type of `TestName` to e.g. `string`, everything works as it should.

For `FlowDocument`, a reference to `PresentationFramework.dll` is needed.

What's going on here?
Anybody able to get this working?

Thanks.

**Future readers:** if something seems unclear or inconsistent with the question, answer ans comments, please note that the original question (to which the answer and some of the comments refer) had different indentation (which affects the code). I am not rolling back the edit, because some of the comments do refer to the indented version. *-- July 31st, Ramon Snir*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work by indenting everything after the first line (NB this has now been done in the code sample in the question), and adding references to PresentationCore, System.Xaml and WindowsBase as well as PresentationFramework.

Not sure this explains your error message, however!

I'm using VS2010 so the behaviour may be different.

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice the wrong identation, I updated the original question.
As for referencing WindowsBase and System.Xaml too, this makes no difference.

Comment: I'm going to do this in VS 2010 now, but I'm suspecting that this is a bug in VS 2012... thanks for the info on that :)

Comment: Did you add PresentationCore as well?  I get your error message if I remove this reference, but it compiles fine if I include it.

Comment: Turns out you were right! I forgot to add a reference to PresentationCore. Now it works just fine. Thanks! (Strange no error message appears, though)

Comment: Great.  Perhaps the missing error message is a problem in VS2012.